# What is the contain method in Django rest_framework Filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have a database that looks like this:

```
{
    name: 'We love Football',
    type: 'Sports',
}
{
    name: 'Let's play Football',
    type: 'Sports'
}
{
    name: 'Let's play Basketball',
    type: 'Sports'
}
```

I need to implement something like this:

```
class GameAPIListView(ListAPIView):
     serializer_class = GameSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        term = self.request.GET['term']
        data = Game.objects.filter(name.contains(term))
        return data
```

If I type "Fooball", the first two items will be returned, since they contain the token "Football". What is the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a question about Django, not Django REST Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try with `name__contains` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/search/#use-cases).  another thing is to search with `icontains` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-icontains) for case insensitive search.

Also if you are using `postgres` database there are so many additional search features [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)
available in django.